# A special way of handling shadows

Tags: rendering, texturing

I do some low poly pixel art on blender, and usually I draw the shadows directly on the UV texture ( It allows me to have a total freedom on the choice of the colors and more) the problem is that the shadows are fixed, I thought about 2 ways to make it dynamic, but I do not know if it's possible to do that on blender, an idea ?

**The kind of stuff I made ->** 
[image: The kind of stuff I made][image: The kind of stuff I made]

**First idea** - Using two textures ( the second texture is a copy of the first but with shaded face)
**Second Idea** - Using a color palette
[image: idea]

**Example with Aseprite shading tool ( it's how I'd like shadows works )**
[image: Second Idea]
[image: other example]

Comment: I'm guessing you want the tiles' materials to remain shadeless, so the surfaces don't _actually_  respond to light using one of the renderer's shading methods, but instead, switch textures in and out according to where the light is? Deliberately faking shadows? Or do you want _actual_ shadows from _actual_ lights?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I edited the images form the first post, maybe it's clearer now.
Currently I'm doing fake shadows, and I'd like Blender to calculate shadow areas and shadows projected in real time, but have better control over the colors / appearance of the shaded part of the texture, with keeping the same result than I've with fake shadow but be able to move the lighting source at any time.

Comment: ..and you'd like the black area to be controllable _pixellated_ shadows, as in the gif above?

Comment: I'd like the black part to affect the texture in the same way as the gif above (following the same rules / choosing colors from a palette) I know it's not realistic, and that it's not very logical with the way that Blender manages the lights, but maybe  it can be done with a shader or others ? when I work in 2D I like the fact of being able to choose the color of my shadows, I would like to do the same in 3D

Comment: In fact I need only 2 or 3 states, enlightened / normal / shaded, and according to these states I want to change the colors of the texture in relation to a given palette

Comment: I think so, but haven't had time to prove it. It would involve shading with a plain white diffuse material, in Blender Internal or EEVEE, and using the resulting tone, (through a threshold,) to drive a switch between textures, or a pixellated, tinted overlay to produce the final surface color.

Comment: I don't get it. First you state that you "usually I draw the shadows directly on the UV texture" then you mention you want to make shadows dynamic. It contradicts each other. First, what is the texture for? Game engine? Rendering? Else something? Second, if you want shadows to be dynamic then you draw textures without them and let shadows to be handled with render engine (game or whatever). There is no reason to change how Blender draws shadows on this object unless you plan rendering in Blender (further it looks like shadows in Blender Internal which is better not to use now).

Comment: I draw them by hand because I can't have a satisfactory result with dynamic shadows. On Blender shadows are like a layer of color that adds all over the texture, if the color of this shadow is blue, all others colors are mixed with blue, but when I choose shadow color ( in 2D for example )  the color of the shadow depend of the color itself, if the element is yellow, the shadow will be not a mixture of yellow and blue but rather orange. if I could have the result that I want directly in Blender it would be enough. Sorry if I'm not clear my english is not really good.